# When I have the choice should I choose traveling on an Airbus 340/330 or a Boeing 777?

Tags: aircraft, boeing, airbus

I am looking for options to travel long distance with the family. I have the choice between an [Airbus 330](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Air_Canada/Air_Canada_Airbus_A330_B.php) or a [Boeing 777](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Air_Canada/Air_Canada_Boeing_777-300.php). The Airbus appears to have pitch between 31-33 and the Boeing is stable at 32. This example is from Air Canada, but if you look at the options at other airlines the same difference can be seen. (eg: KLM [77W](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/KLM/KLM_Boeing_777-300ER.php) and [A332](http://www.seatguru.com/airlines/KLM/KLM_Airbus_A330-200.php)) The choices I am investigating are not shown on seatguru.

When you look at the seatmaps, the Boeing 777 appears to offer a much more "cramped" experience then the Airbus 330. Can be this due to optical illusions? BTW I am flying economy class. First class seems comfortable in both models.

So my question is if the Airbus 330 is a better choice if you fly economy.

Comment: On seatguru the difference between these two models seems consistent.

Comment: As worded this question seems subjective, perhaps even a disguised poll question... What factors do you really want to know? How much space in economy seats in both aircraft or such?

Comment: I always prefer Boeing, but that is because a lot of my friends and family are pilots - I trust their judgement, despite the fact they get the really good seats with the view.

Comment: Most of the airlines I've flown on for long-hauls use the same width seats on A330s, that they uses on their 777s. Neither is inherently 'more cramped' than the other. It's all just a matter of what seats a particular airline chooses to use on particular model of aircraft and it will vary widely from one airline to the next.

Comment: A330 is hands down the best aircraft I've ever flown on. It's a shame they discontinued the production

Comment: @RoryAlsop So essentially you have no experience of flying either and you are just telling us your opinion which is based on people you know who pilot Boeing aircraft. Which has nothing to do with being a passenger in general or anything to do with the 777 and the 330 specifically.

Comment: no @dan-klasson - that's absolutely not what I am saying. I have piloted aircraft since the late 70's, and I have flown over 600 flights as a passenger. So I am unsure why you have made up incorrect assumptions about me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is going to vary strongly from carrier to carrier because as far as I can tell what really matters is how long it's been since the interiors were refurbished (a process airlines do one plane model at a time) and whether the route is considered important by the airline. Sure, you can make some overall opinions about narrowbody (one aisle) vs widebody (two aisles) but not much else. Power, inflight entertainment, and even just the upholstery are all going to matter as much as layout.

If I was travelling alone on AirCanada, I would go with the 330 because two of the three banks of rows have no "middle seat". If I was travelling as a family of three, that same difference would cause me to reject the 330. I guess maybe a family of four would prefer the 330 since you could get two rows of two and have two windows and a little family cluster. However I'm only 5'4" and my shortness is all in my legs, so a 31" pitch doesn't scare me. It might be more of an issue for you.

Answer (score 12):

Personally, I wouldn't base my decision based on A330 vs 777 but on the Carrier's service and reputation, and their in-flight entertainment offering.